# Is Ubuntu for Android by Canonical available to the average user yet?

Tags: android

I recently found out about Ubuntu for Android Multi-Core Smartphones and was digging around on the Ubuntu website as well as the Canonical website but have yet to find any information on if it available to the public yet ?

I am very interested to try it our on my Android and if it is available for the public am wondering where and how I can get a copy of "Ubuntu for Android" ?

If it is not available then perhaps someone can shed some lite on what sort of timeframe it will be until it is available to the general public?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, no.

You can currently try the [Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) preview (though it's only recommended for developers at this time) but I'm not aware of any public preview of Ubuntu for Android