# Ubuntu for Android: status?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

Does anyone know what the current status of this [project](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android) is? I am very eager to try it out, but there does not seem to be any available download, nor information on which handsets/hardware to use.

Comment: does this answer your question?:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/307054/is-ubuntu-for-android-by-canonical-available-to-the-average-user-yet/307060#307060

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but only partly. This post gives the impression the whole project has been abandoned, yet it is still on the official website, which doesn't really seem to add up.

Comment: No future plans have been announced for Ubuntu for Android since the Ubuntu Touch announcement. While it is so to say an abandoned project, there probably was no need to remove it from the website entirely. If people (read: companies or carriers) show interest again the project may be revived. Another reason to keep that page might be to distinguish between Ubuntu Touch and Ubuntu for Android.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That cleared up the point for me. I sincerely hope something will help the whole "dock your cell phone and use it as a PC" idea take off in the near future. It would transform my job quite radically!

Answer (score 0):

The project and status can be found at [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone) in the phone tab.

Right now the project is in early development and the currently supported handsets are the nexus devices.

Comment: OK. Thanks. But is it available for download and testing anywhere?

Comment: You're mixing up Ubuntu Touch (http://www.ubuntu.com/phone) and Ubuntu for Android (http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android).